# UIView Animation <Not Fetched> Crashing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-animation

My program moves an object along CGPoints. When a new amount of CGPoints are created it moves to the new points just fine. After about 5-10 object changes my application crashes and Xcode gets the beach ball.

Here is the animation:

```
-(void)animateDot {
    double x1 = dotMotion.center.x;
    double y1 = dotMotion.center.y;
    double x2 = (*doodlePoints)[dotLocation].x;
    double y2 = (*doodlePoints)[dotLocation].y;
    dist = sqrt(((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1))); 
    if (dist < 0.01){
        dist = 1;
    }
    delay = dist/100.0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animateDot)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:delay];
    dotMotion.center = (*doodlePoints)[dotLocation];
    if (dotLocation == doodlePoints->size()-1){
        dotMotion.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16);
    } else {
        dotMotion.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 8);
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    dotLocation = (dotLocation +1)%doodlePoints->size();
    if (dotLocation == 0 && stopAnimation != YES){
        dotLocation = (dotLocation +1)%doodlePoints->size();
    }
}
```

The button that you click for a new object has this: (and I do call isAnimating == TRUE once, and never call it false, so it shouldn't be doing animationDot again).

```
    if (isAnimating == TRUE) {
} else {
    [doodlePad animateDot];
}
```

My Errors include:

```
Warning: Unable to reach Previous state:
```

Also the stack shows a very large amount of (a couple thousand)

```
# <Not Fetched> //# = 1 to X amount
```

and also my stack starts with:

```
0 szone_malloc_should_clear
1 malloc_zone_malloc
2 _CFRuntimeCreateInstance
3 CFBasicHashCreate
4 __CFDictionaryCreateGeneric
5 CFDictionaryCreate
6 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary int.. //I can't see the rest
7 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObj... //as above
```

then 8 through 100 has

```
# -[DoodlePad animateDot]
# -[UIViewAnimationState sendDel... //can't see the rest
# -[UIViewAnimationState popAni... //above
```

after this its all `# <Not Fetched>`

I have a feeling I need a way of releasing memory or remove the animation before the next CGPoints are created.

Can you explain what  means? I couldn't find anyone with an error like this on Google. How can this crash be fixed?

Comment: You're crashing your app *and* Xcode?

Comment: Yes. I am guessing its crashing my app and when xcode is trying to generate the error and stack issues, its got such a large amount of <not fetched> that is crashing xcode.

Comment: Well, that's an achievement of sorts. Try doing block-style animation (with `UIView animateWithDuration: ...`) instead of how you're doing it. Not sure it will fix your exact problem, but one of the beneficial side-effects of block-style is that it automatically disables user input for all views while the animation is happening, so no need for your `isAnimating` flag.

Comment: ah thanks, hah. the issue with block-style animation is that the customer wants this application working on 3.0 and up. I also need the animation running the while the user interacts. Luckily this apple animation is does automatic threading. Could that be an issue? the thread is building up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is of the wrong form. It should accept three parameters `:::`. The other thing is that you are doing some heavy stuff with heavy objects (UI objects are heavy). It looks like your `delay` may take values as small as `0.01` (**and smaller!!!**). (Its not a *delay*, but *duration* in your case.) This sort of animation does not make sense, as fps on iPhone is 60.

(Are you trying to replace *game loop* with animations? :))

Comment: Actually I am have a GCRect of objects like squares and triangles and I just want an animation to go around the object showing were it begins and ends and then repeats. But thank you for your comment. I learned something i think i am rather lucky to be getting away with only the selector parameter haha.

Comment: Also your correct on the smaller values. The reason why i set up the delay like that is due to the fact we have a circle and this make the animation much smoother and correct. the circle that we are using has atleast 300+ pixels (I have a dimensions to logical conversion)

Comment: Can I get your thoughts on this. Is it possible that when its moving to the first point of a new object after it was already on an object, if you change the object again before the dot gets to the 2nd object it will confuse it and crash it? Cause it seems to crash when the button is pressed too fast.

Comment: thats exactly what it is. If the dot is moving to a new object and if i change that object before it touches the first point in crashes. So whats my alternatives...

Comment: Well... It is still unclear to me what you want to do... :) But again, it looks like you should have some "loop". You should use `CALayer`-s + `CAAnimation`-s. Handling user interaction should be moved elsewhere. (`UIButton` is clickable, indeed... but... looks like abuse.:))

Comment: the button is supposed to give a random object and the dot animates around it. If the person wants to change the object faster to see a new shape they will be like you said abusing the button to find the new shape. Your right i'll try out what your suggesting thanks mate.